# SyntaxError while passing arguments while converting Python 2 to 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an error with this python2 while trying to convert it to python3. I did not write the original 2000 lines of code, but I need to use this plugin for a project with my students, so I'm doing my best here. The interpreter I'm using is stalling with `invalid syntax (lig_alignment.py, line 1102)`

This is the code that is triggering the error:

```py
def cluster_cmp((a1,c1,r1),(a2,c2,r2)):
            return keynat.keynat_cmp(r1,r2)
```

When I try a converter, I just get a 1.
When I type it into an online interpreter I get this error:

```
File "<string>", line 5
 
def cluster_cmp((a1,c1,r1),(a2,c2,r2)):

                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You'll have to define the function with just two parameters - `def cluster_cmp(acr1, acr2):` perhaps.  And then manually split those sequences into their components: `a1, c1, r1 = acr1; a2, c2, r3 = acr2`.

Comment: I was kind of thinking along those lines. Unfortunately, there's another function with the same issue. I guess this will go way beyond a simple conversion. Thanks a lot!